# subversion password prompt in GUI window instead of terminal

Tags: command-line, password, gui, window, svn

I've had this issue plague me on and off on different Ubuntu distros over the years, and I don't understand how it was ever avoided (I thin I managed to rectify it before), and searching for answers comes up with nothing similar to this problem.

When I do an "svn commit" in my terminal (regular bash shell - local keyboard/monitor), rather than a prompt for my svn password immediately appearing in the terminal, the password prompt happens in a popup GUI window (Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome). I would like Ubuntu/subversion to STOP doing that and prompt directly in my terminal.

I do have the usual "store-passwords = no" and "store-plaintext-passwords = no" in my ~/.subversion/servers file, because that's how I like it. But it seems the "password getter" is handed over to the GUI, which creates the popup window, I cancel that, then the "password getter" is handed back to the terminal window, where the normal and expected prompt happens on the next terminal, line, but only because I cancelled the action from the GUI popup window. of course, had I not cancelled the "password getter" window and just entered my password in it and clicked "OK" it would work just fine. But I just don't want it to do that--if I am working in the terminal, then work should stay in the terminal, and the action of getting TEXT INPUT should not be handled by a GUI window (how dumb). (/rant)

Can anyone tell me how to disable the action of my subversion password being prompted for by a GUI window instead of directly in the terminal?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "svn password"? are you connecting to the svn repo locally via plain svn, or via `svn+ssh` - or some other protocol?

Comment: I have a somewhat local apache and subversion server on my home network: sudo apt install subversion libapache2-mod-svn libapache2-svn libsvn-dev       . .... then apache passwords created by: sudo htpasswd -cm /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd admin

Comment: (..... sigh .....)

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `~/.subversion/config` and uncomment the `password-stores` line as explained in the comments:

```
[auth]
### To disable all password stores, use an empty list:
password-stores =
```

the save it and try again.